# How to deploy a multi-tenant django app to AWS?

Tags: django, postgresql, amazon-web-services, multi-tenant

I have an Django+Postgres app that has a multi-tenant structure and I don't have prior experience deploying this type of app to AWS. I have followed the general Elastic Beanstalk tutorial to deploy a simple app. (https://realpython.com/blog/python/deploying-a-django-app-to-aws-elastic-beanstalk/) However, I am looking for a solution that allows me to more flexibly create different "sites". Currently, I have learned to create different sites via this tutorial (http://mycodesmells.com/post/django-tutorial-multi-tenant-setup).

So i have below questions :

1. how to deploy this app (I am leaning toward not using Elastic Beanstalk but just deploying it to EC2)
2. how I could create different sites after deploying this app.

Answer (score 2):

The following should help:

- Set up your `.ebextensions` so your Django project deploys with `eb deploy`.
- Set up `django-storages` with AWS S3 for mediafiles if you need to.
- Purchase a domain and set it up with AWS Route 53 (you can buy via Route 53, too).
- Point your root domain alias to your Elastic Beanstalk app.
- Point a wildcard domain to your app, too.
- Set up AWS SES to save your domain emails to an AWS S3 bucket. You can use other providers as well, SES is just about the easiest.
- Provision AWS ACM certificates for HTTPS support.

You now have your site working under `.example.com` and can use `tenant.example.com`  to refer to a single client's setup - it refers to the same deployment but has a different `Host` header which lets Django tenant schemas to distinguish clients. You have wildcard forwards and do not need any setup other than in Django for adding new tenants.